# Register user info to separate tables

Tags: django

I'd like to save the basic info to Users and additional info to other table. I don't know how I can save email to other heepoo table's `user_id` field. Could you please help me on?

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Mascot.delete()
        super(School, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    username = forms.HiddenInput()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password',)

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HeepooUser
        exclude = ('allow_phone')
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user = user_form.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile = profile_form.save()

            registered = True
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure lot of method is there prefer way is `OneToOneField` to User table

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Thanks to explain Raja. I got one more question :D How can I save the email address to Username field in auth_user table?

Comment: @MrKarl you are asking different question this time...! why you want to save email in username field ?

Comment: @Sorry Raja I'm in chaos with too many bugs ㅜㅜ) I'll ask separate question and thanks to help me!!

Comment: Oh because my form only have email, phone, password and school. So when I try to save it the auth_user table have an error to same null value in username field.